# 14.04 on Macbook Pro always boots to GRUB prompt

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, macbook

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04 on a Macbook Pro. I've also already tried reinstallting that Ubuntu another time. **It's a single-boot system**, i.e. I have no other operating systems installed.

Each time I start it, it boots to the GRUB prompt. Here all I have to do is to load the correct config:

```
configfile (hd2,gpt1)/EFI/grub/grub.cfg
```

This command starts the system without any further problems. **How can I make GRUB start from this config automatically**, i.e. without booting to prompt? I've already tried running `update-grub` and `grub-install /dev/sda`. They finish without errors, but don't make any change.

---

Here is some further information, in case its relevant:

- `mount | grep boot`

  ```
  /dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw)
  ```

- `sudo parted -l`

  ```
  Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54503 (scsi)
  Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
  Partition Table: gpt

  Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
   1      1049kB  538MB  537MB   fat32                 boot
   2      538MB   316GB  315GB   ext4
   3      316GB   320GB  4150MB  linux-swap(v1)
  ```

- `sudo efibootmgr`

  ```
  BootCurrent: 0000
  Timeout: 5 seconds
  BootOrder: 0000
  Boot0000* grub
  Boot0080* 
  Boot0081* Mac OS X
  Boot0082* 
  BootFFFF*
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of headache, I stumbled over [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254348) forum post. Interestingly, the situation explained their is quite contrary to mine:

> The problem is at least partially fixed. **When dumped to the grub shell the "set" command is useful.** It clearly **showed the prefix as being set to "(hd0,gpt1)/boot/grub"**. This folder and the stub grub.cfg did not exist and instead the stub **grub.cfg was in the /EFI/ubuntu folder** in the EFI partition instead. I manually created /boot/grub/ in the EFI partition and copied the stub grub.cfg into it and that was all she took.

For me however, the prefix was `.../efi/ubuntu` but it should be `efu/grub`. To me, it really looks like this is an Ubuntu bug. The proper fix for this issue would be to change the `prefix`, but I also have no idea where it is coming form. **TL;DR:** So instead, *as a work-around*, I copied `/boot/efi/EFI/grub` to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` and voilà.